# Open and read a lot of files with the same ending using Perl

Tags: perl, loops

I have a folder called ALLEQData in which I have 100 files that end in '.ndk' for example, 'jan05.ndk', 'feb05.ndk' etc. 
Using a Perl script I would like to open every single file ending in '.ndk', read the information contained in that file and place it in an output file.
Before I only needed to open one file and read it, for which I used:

```
my $filename = "jan76_dec10.ndk";
open FILEEQ, "<$filename"
    or die "can't open '$filename' for reading: $!";
close FILEEQ;
    $icount = 0;
for ($j=0; $j<@equ_file; $j++) .....etc
```

Then read over the information. I can read and sort the information into the output that I want.

What I am not sure how to do, is how to open all of the file that end in '.ndk', one by one, do the reading and sorting, close that file, then move onto the next one?

Hope this is clear enough.

Comment: You are aware that in your sample code, you close the file right after opening it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use [glob](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/glob.html):

```
my @filenames = glob('*.ndk');

for my $filename (@filenames) {
    open my $fh, '<', $filename
        or die "can't open '$filename' for reading: $!";
    # read/sort file

    close $fh;
}
```

Comment: The glob command works but only reads the first file, I am assuming the this is because it is not in a loop? Thaks

Comment: Are you assigning it to a scalar variable rather than an array? `my $filename = glob('*.nbk');` will return only the first one (subsequent calls will return the rest).

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at [Perl's globbing mechanism](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/glob.html).

Answer (score 1):

You could also read filenames from the command line:

```
while ($#ARGV > -1) {
    my $filename = shift;
    open my $fh, '<', $filename
        or die "can't open $filename for reading: $!";
    # ...
    close $fh;
}
```

Then call your perl script with a wild card expression:

```
your-script.pl *.ndk
```

Comment: Or you could just use the diamond operator `<>`